# Node.js / Express make variable available in layout on all routes

Tags: node.js, express

Once a user has logged in, I want to display their username in the header, which is currently part of `layout.jade`. Their details are in `req.currentUser` but `req` isn't accessible from the layout.

I know I can do the following for each of the `render` calls in my routes:

```
res.render('help', {
    locals: { currentUser: req.currentUser }
});
```

But it seems there must be a better way than adding `{ currentUser: req.currentUser }` into the `locals` every single one of my routes.

I'm still a Node newbie, so apologies if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use a [`dynamic helper`](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#app.dynamichelpers%28%29). It is a function that is passed the `request` and `response` objects, just like any route or middleware, and can return data specific to the current request. (including session data)

So, in app.js:

```
app.dynamicHelpers({
  currentUser: function (req, res) {
    return req.currentUser;
  }
});
```

and in your template:

```
<div><%= currentUser %></div>
```

Comment: 'app.dynamicHelpers' seem to be deprecated in express v3 and replaced with 'app.use'

Comment: For those like me who will stumble into this answer a few years later, here's what you need to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580796/migrating-express-js-2-to-3-specifically-app-dynamichelpers-to-app-locals-use