# How to include server-side script in Jade template?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I've just installed [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/); now I want to access `moment` inside my Jade template. Example:

```
.main-content
    .container
        .access-details.clearfix
            .left
                div Logged in: <b>#{user.name}</b>
                div Access Lvl: #{user.accessLevel}
            .right
                div= moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a")
```

To be clear, I want the date to be formatted server-side and then sent to the client as a rendered string.

So how do I make a JavaScript library available inside of a Jade template?

---

I should probably note that I'm using this with Express:

```
var server = express.createServer();
server.configure(function () {
    server.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

Is there some options I have to pass in there somehow to tell it which libraries to include?

---

Just occured to me that this is absolutely no different than passing in a local variable. e.g.,

```
server.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        locals: {
            moment: require('moment')
        }
    });
});
```

But I don't want to pass this in to every view; if I ever forgot it my app would break as it's used in the main layout. So how do I make sure it's always available?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Helpers are removed from Express 3 or 4.

Kindly use [`app.locals`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html)

```
app.locals.moment = require('moment');
```

The `app.locals` object is a JavaScript Object. The properties added to it will be exposed as local variables within the application.

So you can use `app.locals` in any view files, `Jade` or `EJS`;

```
moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss');
```

Answer (score 8):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7244152/65387) got my pointed in the right direction, although the documentation on `dynamicHelpers` seems to have mysteriously disappeared from the Express documentation.

Also, I didn't need a *dynamic* helper, just a static one (no access to request/response). So I took a stab in the dark at what it would be called:

```
server.helpers({
    moment: require('moment')
});
```

Works like a charm! `moment` is now available in all my views.

Comment: Helpers concept has been removed from Express 3. What you mean by ”static helpers” is [`app.locals`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals) (`app.locals.moment = require('moment');`). For `.dynamicHelpers` use middlewares.